# Знаки препинания

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Поясните, пожалуйста, расстановку знаков в 2 предложениях

-Каким быть ему зависит лишь от тебя.(Запятая вроде не нужна, почему?)

-У нас вообще принято, если идешь прямо по большой дороге, то и продолжай свой путь по ней же.(Вопрос по запятой перед если).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом предложении тире обусловлено интонационным отделением придаточной части от главной. Чаще всего тире употребляется, когда главной части предшествует 1) придаточная изъяснительная (***ваш случай***). 
Во втором предложении запятая отделяет придаточное условное.
Подробнее о случаях употребления тире в придаточном предложении, см. ***Справочник практикум. Д.Э. Розенталь. Москва, Оникс. 2007г. Стр.266.******

Comment: Каким быть ему - зависит лишь от тебя. Так верно?

Comment: Да, вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что второе предложение больше похоже на БСП: У нас вообще принято: если идешь прямо по большой дороге, то и продолжай свой путь по ней же.

Вообще, в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными могут использоваться союзы КОГДА и ЕСЛИ, но это частные случаи, например: Беда, если заблудишься в лесу. Хорошо, когда все дома.

Comment: В БСП после двоеточия можно поставить "а именно". Здесь вряд ли поставишь "а именно". В придаточном изъяснительном могут также использоваться союзы как, как будто, как бы, чтобы. 

София, я вас не очень понял. Второе предложение вы относите тоже к придаточному изъяснительному? Да?

Comment: Можно заменить: "У нас вообще принято, что если идешь прямо по большой дороге, то и продолжай свой путь по ней же". А Вы как думаете?

Comment: Да,конечно!

Answer (score 1):

***Каким быть ему - зависит лишь от тебя.*** Подлежащее в виде безличного предложения КАКИМ БЫТЬ ЕМУ (инфинитивное подлежащее, точнее глагольно-именной оборот). Сказуемое ЗАВИСИТ. Ставится тире. [можно здесь посмотреть](http://studopedia.ru/3_79385_podlezhashchee-i-sposobi-ego-virazheniya.html)

***У нас вообще принято: если идешь прямо по большой дороге, то и продолжай свой путь по ней же.***
Бессоюзная связь между первой и второй частью (вторая часть представляет собой сложноподчинённое предложение, союз если присоединяет второе предложение к третьему, а не к первому.) СПП дополняет первую часть*. **Ставится двоеточие.***